# Как узнать, какой объем на диске будут занимать файлы?

Tags: информатика, fat32

Допустим, спрашивают, на диске (FAT32) записаны 3 файла размером 5кб, 9кб и 15кб. Какой объем на диске будут занимате все файлы? Как узнать ответ в кб?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У FAT32 есть понятие кластера.

Кластер - это минимальная часть дискового простанства, котрую можно выделить для размещения файла. Размер кластера различен в различных дисках, но в общем всегда равен величине 512 байт умноженной на степень двойки. (512 байт - это сектор в старых дисках, в которых и находит применениеи FAT32)

Таким образом, вопрос с подвохом. Тому, кто его задал, надо ответить вопросом "А кластер какого размера?"

Предположим, вам говорят "4 кб!"

Тогда первый файл занимает два кластера, второй - три кластера, третий - 4 кластера, а все вместе они занимают 9 кластеров или 36 килобайт.